# C++ arrays with unknown size

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to implement a program which gives you a sequence with a determined start, end and base, problem is that i cannot determine what will be the number of elements

this is my code for a simple arithmetic progression generator

```
float Arithmetic_squence[](float start, float end, float b) {
  float result[];
  float last_number = start;
  while (last_number <= (end - b)) {
    result[sizeof(result)] = last_number;
    last_number += b;
  }
}
```

it won't compile because it wants a size

i also want the code as simple as possible so i wish i won't have to implement a non-efficient, time consuming linked list

i also don't know how to deal with vectors, maybe if there's a quick guide i may use it

Comment: About a quick guide, (Hint) google "c++ vector" -> first result is http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/

Comment: ¤ Others have already mentioned `std::vector`. And if you really needed an array, that would be a fine choice. However, an array is seldom a good choice for representing an arithmetic sequence. For example, the `rand` function is a function, not an array. Define instead an object with the information needed to compute the next number in the sequence, and let it offer a member function `next`. You might also or alternatively choose to express it as a C++ forward iterator, but I think an adapter for that is better, if it turns out to be needed. So, stateful object, not array. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Alf, that's a good idea for an expert coder, but probably a little extreme to ask of a novice...

Comment: @StilesCrisis: it's not for expert coders, it's not "advanced". although i'm sure that if the user interface folks at Microsoft were let at it, they would label it "advanced". they even labeled the button to edit environment variables (in the system applet) as "advanced". we get to the point where even farting is "advanced", only for expert gourmets. i think that's silly. :-) cheers,

Comment: Okay, you can keep on believing that implementing an STL adapter or forward iterator is for beginners. The guy doesn't know how to use `std::vector` yet, though, so I stand by my original statement.

Comment: @StilesCrisis I cannot agree there. If it is good at the end, why have novices learn bad patterns and then have them relearn? My experience is that it is harder to get someone out of a bad habit than it is to teach then right in the first place. That is why I love "accelerated c++" as learning material: it avoids the common pattern of teaching C before C++, and letting bad habits crawl in

Comment: @StilesCrisis: you are **misrepresenting** what I wrote. i conclude that you are a troll.

Comment: @StilesCrisis note that the original suggestion is to create a stateful object, not an iterator adapter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use `std::vector`, the standard library implementation of a runtime-resizeable array:

```
vector<float> Arithmetic_squence(float start, float end, float b) {
  vector<float> result;

  float last_number = start;

  while (last_number <= (end - b)) {
    result.push_back(last_number);
    last_number += b;
  }

  return result;
}
```

The `vector` named `result` starts out empty and adds elements each time you do `push_back`.

You can get the number of elements in a vector with the `size()` member function:

```
vector<float> f = Arithmetic_squence(x, y, z);

for (int i = 0; i < f.size(); ++i)
    cout << f[i] << endl;
```

`vector` becomes a very powerful tool when you learn the ins and outs of the Standard Library (iterators, algorithms, etc); see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector for a reference to `std::vector`, and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ for a general C++ Standard Library reference, up to date with the C++11 standard.

Comment: You need a "return result;" statement.

Comment: @Mr_C64 whoops thanks, that's what you get for copy/pasting code I guess

Comment: yes thanks, it seems i'll have to learn about vectors (which is not a bad thing), thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Using `std::vector`<sup>[[tutorial]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)</sup> would be best in this case:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<float> Arithmetic_squence(float start, float end, float b) {
  std::vector<float> result;
  float last_number = start;

  while (last_number <= (end - b)) {
    result.push_back(last_number);
    last_number += b;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have **variable length arrays(VLA)** in C++.
Some compilers support variable length arrays as an compiler extension But If you use those your code will be non portable as it is non standard conformant.
The best choice is to simply Use **[std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `std::vector` to implement an array of variable size.

If this is too complicated, make `result[]` the biggest possible size you could ever want, and `assert` that `end - start` isn't too large to fit. That's what I did when I was a novice programmer and templates were too daunting.